# How do I get the sound working on a Dell Dimension 5000?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, dell

I have recently installed 12.04 LTS on a Dell Dimension 5000 from a USB with the disk image. It is a fresh install, and from the off, I noticed that the sound was not working.

I kinda expected this, but I have minor knowledge of Ubuntu and all the forum post replies seem to be tailored to the asker (I.E their details are asked for and the solution is found from that.

What can I do to get sound?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run updates, to complete installation?

Have you checked for 'alternative drivers'?

---

**IF SO**, then start sound troubleshooting:

[Wiki: DebuggingSoundProblems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems)

Comment: What do you mean by alternative drivers?

Comment: System Settings (icon at top right of screen) >> Hardware >> Additional Drivers